# Google Analytics (Page-view)

Tags: google-analytics, cookie, page-views

I have a question, is it possible to count "page views" in Google Analytics even if the user does not accept the cookie consent? That is, to continue counting visits to your page anonymously. When I reject cookies, Analytics stops registering these visits. Even if I have to hire a Google Tag Manager Server Side, I wouldn't have a problem. I find a thousand answers about this but none are clear. If I had to use an API, I wouldn't have any problem either. If anyone knows of a way to continue registering this event, I would be very grateful. Sorry for my level of English.